# Selecting the right data for a user

Tags: php, mysql, select

i have two tables in my data base

[image]

U_ID of table tasks is a foreign key of id from table users

my code is like this

```
<?php
    require("common.php");
    if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        header("Location: login.php");
        die("Redirecting to login.php");
    }
    $query = "
        SELECT
            id,
            username,
            eID
        FROM users
        WHERE id <> '5'
    ";
    $query1 = "
        SELECT
            T_ID,
            task_tom,
            U_ID
        FROM tasks
        ORDER BY T_ID DESC LIMIT 1

    ";
    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

        try
    {
        $stmt1 = $db->prepare($query1);
        $stmt1->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
    $rows1 = $stmt1->fetchAll();
?>
<h1>Memberlist</h1>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Employee ID</th>
        <th>Task</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($rows as $row): foreach($rows1 as $row1): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['eID'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row1['task_tom']; ?></td>
           <?php endforeach; endforeach;?>
</table>
<br/>
<a href="edit_account.php">Edit Account</a><br /><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

my question is how could i populate the task column in the table with correspond to the right U_ID.
this code will provide me this answer

[image]

supposedly, SSIS(data mining) is just the task_tom assigned to bassil and lawrence should have a blank task because the user didnt input any task for lawrence just yet but it seems i have a flaw to my select statement or is it my for each wherein its printing it on the table to every user. so my question is how to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: dont use two queries.. instead join them with the user id

Comment: could you please explain to me further my good sir

Comment: ok seeing that your task each task has its respective user id. you can connect you task table u_id to users table id to generate only 1 results that is what you output look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    U.id,
    U.username,
    U.eID, 
    t.task_tom

FROM 
    users u

  INNER JOIN 
   (
      SELECT u_id, max(t_id) as t_id
      FROM tasks
      GROUP BY u_id
   ) tmax
  ON tmax.U_ID = u.id

  INNER JOIN tasks t ON t.t_id = tmax.t_id

WHERE u.id <> '5'
```

This basically says "what is the latest task id for each user, now get me all info about that task".

Comment: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Comment: @Yinks sorry couldn't see your table def while typing. Try it now.

Comment: this one works but it wont display any other members unless they have a task assigned to them. is there any way to jsut fetch their names even without task assigned?

Comment: Yes, change joins to LEFT, as INNER excludes results that don't join.

Comment: @Yinks sorry, yes. Ref previous comment. Thanks for the accept, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` your tables using `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` As per your requirement.

```
    SELECT
        id,
        username,
        eID,
        T_ID,
        task_tom,
        U_ID
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN tasks ON tasks.U_ID = users.id
    WHERE users.id <> '5'
    ORDER BY tasks.T_ID DESC
    GROUP BY users.id
```

Edited the answer, But I am not sure about the working of

```
ORDER BY tasks.T_ID DESC
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: could you please show me how to do this advance type of statement

Comment: Execute this query same way as what you are doing before, which will give you joined table result.

Comment: ok thanks for this but now how could i have a limit of 1 per user?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT U.id,T.T_ID,task_tom FROM users U LEFT JOIN tasks T ON U.id = T.T_ID WHERE id <> '5' ORDER BY T.T_ID DESC group by U.id";
```